# How to group base on occurrences across months?

Tags: pandas, data-science

I have the following dataframe:

| userid | month |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | jan |
| user2 | jan |
| user3 | jan |
| user1 | feb |
| user3 | feb |
| user1 | march |

if user appears more than 2 months, I will group them as active, else no active. The desired output is:

| userid | month | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | jan,feb,march | true |
| user2 | jan | false |
| user3 | jan,feb | false |

how can i do it with pandas? pardon me if i do not have a starting code, as i am totally unsure. dont mind helping a newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `join` and lambda function:

```
df = df.groupby('userid').agg(month = ('month', ','.join), 
                              active=('month', lambda x: len(x) > 2))
print (df)
                month  active
userid                       
user1   jan,feb,march    True
user2             jan   False
user3         jan,feb   False
```

Or count groups and reassign boolean:

```
df = (df.groupby('userid').agg(month = ('month', ','.join), active=('month','size'))
        .assign(active = lambda x: x['active'].gt(2)))
```